# Не получается соединить js файлы как commonjs модули (где ошибка)?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, npm, commonjs

Помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку в коде.

Имеем:
**test.json** - содержит контент (текст), который будет загружен на веб-страницу.
**test.js** - содержит функцию, которая посылает Ajax запрос к test.json, парсит, компилирует с Handelbars Temlate и помещает контент в HTML страницу (с помощью innerHTTML).
**addcontent.js** - javascript файл, который вызывает функцию из **test.js**
**index.html** - cсодержит Handlebars Template, Div, куда будет помещен контент и ссылку (линк) на addcontent.js.

Все работает, если в **index.html** находится ссылка прямо на **test.js**.
Все работает, если обернуть код в **test.js** в функцию с переменными и вызвать ее в этом же файле.

Но когда я пытаюсь вызвать эту функцию в **addcontent.js**, соединив **addcontent.js** и **test.js** как commonJS модули, это не работает (запустив локальный сервер, я вижу пустую страницу по адресу localhost:8080).

Не вижу ошибку в синтаксисе.
Проверял файлы онлайн-валидаторами.
Проверял через консоль разработчика, ругается на непонятный ей синтаксис commonjs:
ReferenceError: module is not defined
ReferenceError: require is not defined

Я только осваиваю commonjs, скачал библиотеку через npm, в index.html подключил /node_modules/commonjs/lib/system.js (правильно?) - результат тот же.

**Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с этим тестовым примером, я только осваиваю модульный метод.**

P.S. Использую NodeJS, NPM, в конечном итоге буду объединять все js файлы с помощью browserify.

https://jsfiddle.net/pf33u8km/

```js
/* test.js */


module.exports = function(jsonDir, templId, finId){
function sendGet(callback) {
    /* create an AJAX request using XMLHttpRequest*/
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    /*reference json url taken from: http://www.jsontest.com/*/

    /* Specify the type of request by using XMLHttpRequest "open", 
       here 'GET'(argument one) refers to request type
       "http://date.jsontest.com/" (argument two) refers to JSON file location*/
    xhr.open('GET', jsonDir);

    /*Using onload event handler to check status of the request*/
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            callback(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
        } else {
            alert(xhr.statusText);
        }
    };

    /*Using onerror event handler to check error state, if the request failed to get the data*/
    xhr.onerror = function () {
        alert("Network Error");
    };

    /*send the request to server*/
    xhr.send();
}

//For template-1
var dateTemplate = document.getElementById(templId).innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(dateTemplate);

sendGet(function (response) {
    document.getElementById(finId).innerHTML += template(response);
})
}
```

```css
/* test.json */
{
   "time": "03:47:36 PM",
   "milliseconds_since_epoch": 1471794456318,
   "date": "08-21-2016-123",
    "test": "lalala 123"
}

/* addcontent.js */
var addContent = require('./test');

addContent("json/test.json", "date-template", 'testData');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="handlebars-v4.0.5(2).js"></script>
</head>

    
<body>
    
    <!-- template-1 -->
<div id="testData"></div>
<script id="date-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  Date:<span> <b>{{date}}</b> </span> <br/> Time: <span><b>{{time}}</b>
    
    </span>
</script>
    
    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/commonjs/lib/system.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="addcontext.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Выше я поместил код из test.json и addcontent.js , разделив комментарием, просто для того чтобы удобно было посмотреть код во всех файлах.

Comment: commonjs: ReferenceError: module is not defined ReferenceError: require is not defined - а кто по-вашему делает их defined?)

Comment: Что такое test/all.js? и Все-таки addcontent.js или addcontext.js?

Comment: Вообще не вникая глубоко скажу что скорее всего проблема в том, что браузер, в отличие от ноды, вообще по дефолту commonjs модули не понимает. Задачу транслирования commonjs модулей в форму, понятную браузеру, берет на себя обычно сборщик (browserify в вашем случае), но его вроде еще нет, так?

Comment: @Утка defined их делает видимо библиотека commonjs, которую я видимо неправильно подключил? Упс, это результат уже моих экспериментов-ковыряний, сейчас исправлю в коде (изначально это ссылка на node_modules/commonjs/lib/system.js). AddconteNT.js. Да, я собираюсь использовать browserify, но разве commonjs модули не могут работать до объединения в единый js файл? Вроде бы по урокам именно так, но нигде пока не нашел инструкции по подключению библиотеки commonjs, примеры сразу начинаются с написания модулей.

Comment: @Утка прав. Надо не _собираться использовать_ Browserify а просто **брать и использовать**. Ни один браузер ничего не знает о спецификации common.js. Ну и как обычно -- если в уроках все так, как вы говорите, то пора выкидывать уроки на помойку

Comment: @MaximVelichkin. У javascript есть разные среды исполнения. Есть браузеры. Они commonjs не умеют из коробки, (потому что commonjs модули служат для синхронной загрузки ресурсов, а браузеру нужно уметь асинхронную). Есть нода. Нода commonjs из коробки умеет. Поэтому если взять и просто накопипастить откуда попало, что-то может пойти не так)

Comment: Ну и заодно, common.js - не библиотека, которую вы, почему-то подключаете/не подключаете, а спецификация формата описания модулей.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Мне тоже казалось что это просто способ написания модулей, но что же тогда я скачиваю через npm install commonjs? На одном форуме всколзь упомянули что я не подулючил commonjs к веб-странице -отсюда мои ысли что это библиотека. Ок, перехожу к browserify, попробую объединить эти модули и запустить все еще раз.

Comment: @MaximVelichkin, не нужно вам подключать никакую commonjs библиотеку. Browserify все соберет в лучшем виде (если вы, конечно, сможете его настроить правильно).

Comment: @MaximVelichkin эту библиотеку надо выкинуть на помойку. Серьезно. Судя по ее странице на сайте npm и по гитхабу - это просто чьи-то упражнения.

Comment: @Утка, @ Dmitriy Simushev, спасибо за разъяснения, тогда пошел разбираться с  browserify!..

Comment: @MaximVelichkin, а заодно и уроки, которые рекомендуют использовать этот хлам пора выкидывать на помойку. В сети куча **нормальных** источников информации по теме

Comment: Ну то есть вас не смущает что у этой "библиотеки" версия 0.0.1, первый он же последний коммит 6 лет назад?

Comment: @Утка Да, интересно)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev А можно подробнее о нормальных источниках пожалуйста?

Comment: @MaximVelichkin, как вам сказал уже Дмитрий, commonjs - это название формата модулей. А то что кто-то свою "супербиблиотеку" так назвал - это на его совести

Comment: @Утка Теперь понятно, спасибо